# "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)" eror when accessing string value for id

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React with Typescript and I'm trying to access a string with the key name id inside of an array of 10 objects containing the id.  The screenshot containing code gives the desired output inside the console but I get the error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'".  I am pretty sure I messed something up earlier which is why I can't just access the value by doing [index].id which is what I attempted prior to the earlier attempt  because it returns "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'". I am very stuck as to why it won't let me access the id like it normally would and would appreciate any help.
Thank you

[Code to generate the links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKhae.png)

[variable named: upcomingMangaIdArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdFfD.png)

[variable named: mangaFileNames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCrZu.png)

[state declarations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSFoO.png)

Comment: Never post images of code. Provide a [mre].

Comment: The type of `upcomingMangaIdArray` defined is `string[]`. But what your log showed in that second link is it is not an array of strings at all, but an array of objects. This implies that something somehow called `setUpcomingMangaIdArray` with a type that's not allowed. Probably its the type itself that is wrong. However, we need to see where `setUpcomingMangaIdArray` is being called, since it implies that area of the code is not type safe. As the persons said above, you should add the code to the question instead of images.

Comment: Understood, I will provide a minimal reproducible example next time. I ended up getting it figured out from adsy's comment.  Not sure how I missed that those were arrays of objects but after changing some code for that and restructuring elsewhere I got it.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Typescript error states `index` has implicitly `any` type. In your forEach loop specify the type of `index` as the type it should be. e.g. if it is a number:

```
mangaFileNames.forEach((element: string, index: number) => {
  // your code here
})
```

If you're sure about the type of variable, you can tell typescript about it this way (generally it is better to avoid):

```
mangaFileNames.forEach((element: string, index) => {
  temp.push(upcomingMangaIdArrray[index as number]["id"])
})
```

Now to the second part: Typescript errors are only for development, that's the reason you get correct output in your console despite of the **Typescript** error